# Nutch Crawling Path - View Hops in solr

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

Is there a possibility to track in which depth nutch found the link and what is the parent link of this one.

It would be very interesting for my project to see in solr where did the crawler came from and maybe as a result I can create a dependency tree in which the user can see where how this link is connected to the root.

Is the linked data an option in nutch or do I need another programm to manage this?

Answer (score 1):

Nutch keeps the relations between pages in the linkdb, however it is not used by default when indexing. The easiest way to do this would be to write a custom plugin or hack the scoring-depth one so that it keeps the parent link.

The depth can be tracked by activating the scoring-depth plugin, you could combine it with the index-metadata plugin to store the metadata '*depth*' into the index.

You might find it easier to do this with [StormCrawler](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler) instead as it tracks the depth and the full path by default. Those can then be indexed into SOLR simply by specifying the key names in indexer.md.filter.

Comment: Can you give a little example which objects I could use?

I've got the choice between "Text url, NutchDocument doc, CrawlDatum dbDatum, CrawlDatum fetchDatum, Parse parse, Inlinks inlinks, float initScore". I would search it in NutchDocument but I can't find a good HowTo. 
Inlinks could be another possibility but this would be the "child link", right?